# How to run a script in another server

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script in one server. I want to run it in another server from this server. Both servers have ubuntu 18.04. I can ssh into the other machine. Do I need to upload my script on another server.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh user@otherserver -T < myscript.sh
```